# Unable to locate the referenced ID using selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to locate a search box with id as (search2) from a website. I have been able to successfully login to the website using the below code.

```
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
tgt = "C:\\mypath"
profile = {"plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled":False, "name":"Chrome PDF Viewer"}],
    "download.default_directory" : tgt}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",profile)
print(options)
driver.get("http://mylink.com/")
user=driver.find_element_by_id("username")
passw=driver.find_element_by_id("password")
user.send_keys("abc@xyz.com")
passw.send_keys("Pwd")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/button').click()
page=driver.find_element_by_id("search2")
print(page)
```

---

The code works perfectly till here but the moment I add the below to it I get an error

```
page.send_keys("abc")
```

---

The error that I get is as below.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

---

What I am trying to do here is login to the website and search for some items and download the results. I have already tried using the implicitly wait options as mentioned in the code. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Once the _url_ `http://mylink.com/` I don't see any field identified as `find_element_by_id("username")` and `find_element_by_id("password")`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you post the html for search2 element ?

Comment: <input type="text" id="search2" aria-label="Text input with segmented button dropdown" ng-class="bc.autoCompleteVisible ? 'search-box-input-searching' : 'search-box-input'" placeholder="What are you searching for?" data-ng-model="bc.autoCompleteQuery" pi-enter="addSearchAsTextFilter(textSearch)" pi-esc="clearSearch()" data-ng-focus="searchBoxFocus(true)" data-ng-blur="searchBoxFocus(false)" ng-trim="false" autocomplete="off" class="ng-pristine ng-valid search-box-input ng-touched">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the below piece of code did the trick. Had to make the current thread sleep while the program continues to run the next steps.

```
time.sleep(5)
```

Thanks everyone.